# Dejo de funcionar la integración de php con googlespreadsheet

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando con Google Spreadsheet API 3. Tengo este código que hasta el día 19 funcionaba correctamente

```
<?php
// Composer's auto-loading functionality
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

//
/*
* Aquí van los datos de la sección credenciales del proyecto que creamos con Google Console
* Modificarlos según su propia direccion de correo y Id de cliente
*/
$nombreAplicacion = "PhpSheet";
$direccionCorreo = "addrowinsheet@phpsheet.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
$idCliente = "3a5bbd2c9ada9a0f85e8fc1516157400c754d6fa";

// Nombre del SpreadSheet creada
$nombreSpreahSheet = "Php Sheet volcado";
// Nombre de hoja de cálculo
$hojaCalculo = "Hoja 2";

$scope = array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds');

// Inicializamos Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName($nombreAplicacion);
$client->setClientId($idCliente);

// credenciales, scope y archivo p12. Agregar el correcto Path al archivo p12
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
$direccionCorreo,
$scope,
file_get_contents('PhpSheet-3a5bbd2c9ada.p12')
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

// si expiro el access token generamos otro
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
$client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

// Obtenemos el access token
$obj_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
$accessToken = $obj_token->access_token;

// Inicializamos google-spreadsheet-client
$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

//Obtenemos los Spreadsheets disponibles para las credenciales actuales
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();

// Obtenemos la spreadsheet por su nombre
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($nombreSpreahSheet);

// Obtenemos las hojas de cálculo de la spreadsheet obetenida
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();

// Obtenemos la hoja de cálculo por su nombre
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($hojaCalculo);
$listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

/*
 * Array de datos a agregar.
 * Observar que el valor de la claves del array que representan los encabezados
 * de las columnas van en minúsculas, en vez de Email sería email.
 * Esto es porque los encabezados de columna deben coincidir exactamente
 * con lo que fue devuelto por la API de Google y no por lo que se ve en Google Drive.
 */
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre'])&&!empty($_SESSION['gclid'])) {
$dataAgregar = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar);
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['nombre2'])&&!empty($_SESSION['gclid2'])) {
  $dataAgregar2 = array('gclid' => $_SESSION['gclid2'],
'nombre' => $_SESSION['nombre2'],
 'email' => $_SESSION['email2'],
 'telefono' =>"'" .$_SESSION['phone2'],
 'mensaje' => $_SESSION['mensaje2'],
 'landing' =>  $landingP2
 );
 $listFeed->insert($dataAgregar2);
}    
?>
```

El día 20 de Mayo de repente ha dejado de funcionar lo que realizaba este código, este código lo tengo puesto en mi contact.php de cada formulario de correo para obtener los datos que introduce el cliente y guardarlos en un google spreadsheet para luego realizar unos informes. No se si por las políticas de privacidad esto esta capado y no dejan hacerlo pero es muy raro que deje de funcionar de la noche a la mañana cuando lleva más de 2 años funcionando.

Alguna Idea?

---

Tras realizar algunos consejos que me ha indicado en comentarios os comento:

1- He mirado los Logs y tenemos unas advertencias. aqui os las pongo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he estado investigando y creo que puede ser el tema de la versión de la API de google spreadsheet.

Adjunto los errores en formato texto

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined     function request_filesystem_credentials() in     /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php:93, referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-admin/includes/class-automatic-upgrader-skin.php(47): WP_Upgrader_Skin->request_filesystem_credentials(false, '/var/www/vhosts...', true), referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php(144): Automatic_Upgrader_Skin->request_filesystem_credentials(false, '/var/www/vhosts...', true), referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-admin/includes/update.php(85): WP_Automatic_Updater->should_update('core', Object(stdClass), '/var/www/vhosts...'), referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-includes/update.php(215): find_core_auto_update(), referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): wp_ in /var/www/vhosts/carbray.es/httpdocs/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php on line 93, referer: http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/b/english/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1526718255.1091089248657226562500
```

Esto son los warnings que me salen

No se si tenéis alguna idea de como solucionarlo

Comment: Revisa el log de errores de PHP y te dirá lo que está ocurriendo. En casos como estos puedes estar pasando miles de cosas. Lo mejor es ir directamente al log de errores.

Comment: Como dices en tu propia pregunta, puede que tengas que por las políticas de privacidad deje de funcionar, simplemente porque ha entrado en vigor la nueva normativa europea LOPD de protección de datos. Comprueba que has aceptado los nuevos términos de uso y que no requieren "algun" nuevo requisito para que funcione tu servicio.

Comment: Juan Jose, no nos ha llegado ingun mail de google spreadsheet para este tema

Comment: Has incluído la [tag:google-apps-script] pero no parece que estas usando esto sino alguna de las APIs ¿cuál versión estás usando? ¿la [V3](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/) o [la más reciente](https://developers.google.com/sheets/)?

Comment: Hola Rúben, estoy utilizando la V3 creo es la versión de asimlqt, concretamente esta https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, por cierto, no olvides de incluir el @ previo al nombre de los usuarios que no son el OP para que les llegue una notificación. Con respecto a las advertencias de error, en lugar de ponerlas como imagen agrega el texto, así son más fáciles de leer y encontrar.

Comment: @Rubén Ya he actualizado la entrada